# Why does Indy 10.6 FTPServer open 2 new connections to transfer files

Tags: ftp, connection, indy

I'm setting up an FTP Server with Indy 10.6 and the initial connection from the client (filezilla) opens up one connection with the server and I'm logged in fine.  When I download any files from the server, it opens 2 more connections (OnConnect fires 2 more times), so now there are 3 connections to the server from the same client.

Is this required or is something not set correctly in the server?  If it is required, how many total connections can I expect a single client to open?

Answer (score 1):

`TIdFTPServer` *does not* open 3 connections for a single transfer, and certainly will not fire the `OnConnect` event multiple times for it.

The FTP protocol only uses 2 connections per client session - 1 for exchanging commands/responses, and 1 for each data transfer.  Files are downloaded sequentially, so there is only ever one data connection alive at a time.

The only way you could be getting multiple `OnConnect` events is if the client is opening multiple command connections.  Data connections do not trigger the `OnConnect` event (they trigger the `OnDataPortBeforeBind` and `OnDataPortAfterBind` events instead).

FileZilla does have the ability to download multiple files in parallel, and that requires establishing multiple FTP connections.  You can limit this in FileZilla's Settings:

[image: settings]

Comment: Perfect, that did it ;)